# Change button value based on selected li

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code :

```
<div id="select-option" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Select your option <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 5/a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

now I have a problem to change that text `'Select your option'` based on li selected using jquery.

and remove `btn-danger` so that the color will change too.

I tried to change using `<select>` tag but the style is not same with `btn-danger`.

any idea how to change it?

I tried to do simple alert box to test if jquery can be applied to this, but no luck :

```
$("#select-option").change(function () {
alert("Hello world.");
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have done so far?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : I even didn't find any luck to show alert box using this : $("#select-option").change(function () { <<< SHOW ALERT >>> };

Comment: @RobertHanson: That's because a Bootstrap dropdown isn't a form field control. Read up on the Bootstrap dropdown and its events.

Comment: `#select-option` is div which do not supports change event since it is not an input element.

Comment: better write a click event for the `li`'s inside `.dropdown-menu`

Answer (score 2):

Your code didn't give you an alert because a Bootstrap dropdown isn't a form field, and doesn't have a `change` event.

If we look at the [Dropdown documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns), we see that there are events triggered when the dropdown is shown and when it's hidden. There are also, of course, going to be `click` events on the `li` elements if the user clicks on one. You probably want to handle `click` on the `li`s.

In terms of changing that text, your best bet is to put it in a span of its own, probably with a class on it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="message">Select your option</span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

...so that you can readily target it with a selector and use `text` to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu>li>a").on('click',function(){
        var val=$(this).html(); 
        $("#select-option >button").html(val);
    })
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/rts61emf/

Answer (score 1):

try this code

Live **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/mpzynkep/)**

HTML

```
<div id="select-option" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class='listname'>Select your option </span><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

    $(".dropdown-toggle .listname").text($(this).text());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I already got the answer...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select-option li").click(function(){
   alert("The LI was clicked.");
  });
});
</script>
```

I'll take it from here...

Answer (score -2):

write function for every li element i.e. onclick="yourFuctionName(your Specified Value)" and in javascript you can easily do what ever you want from that data